# How to get latest comment avtivity on Disqus

Tags: disqus

I have read disqus documentation. I know that we can get latest comments on disqus but i want to display list of pages with respect to recent comment activity. forexample

1. Any-webpage1-title-here                   (Last Comment 5 Minutes Ago)
2. Any-webpage2-title-here                   (Last Comment 15 Minutes Ago)

   ....

Each page has its own disqus identifier.